# PHP: PEAR email sends only on second pass

Tags: php, pear

I am using pear to send email using the code below, on the first time through I get this error every time:

> "Failed to set sender: aa@bb.com [SMTP: Invalid response code received
>   from server (code: -1, response: )]"

If I debug and set the execution point back to 'Re-run from here' after the send, it works fine - almost like something is not initialised properly first time round - anyone have any ideas on this?

```
require_once "Mail.php";

function SendEMail() {

     $from = "Sender Sender <sender@example.com>";
     $to = "AA BB <aa@bb.com>";
     $subject = "Test";
     $body = "This is a test";

     $host = "myhost";

     $headers = array ('From' => $from,
                        'To' => $to,
                        'Subject' => $subject);

     //Re-run from here        
     $smtp =& Mail::factory('smtp',
       array ('host' => $host,
         'auth' => false,
         'username' => '',
         'password' => ''));

     $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

     if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
        $s = $mail->getMessage();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Assuming this is in a loop? Give more code to we can take a look...

Comment: I have simplified my code and edited the post - still get the problem with the code as-is above.

Comment: No looping, once-off call

Answer (score 0):

Use wireshark to find out which response you really get from the server. Maybe the server has activated greylisting, so that you can't send a mail the first time.

Comment: There isn't anything like that as I'm running a personal smpt for testing , it works fine with php's built-in smtp but just behaves strangely with the pear version

Comment: so you say you can't use wireshark to analyze network traffic because what exactly?

Comment: I didn't say that I can't use wireshark, just that there cannot be any greylisting or similar problems. I can only assume that this is some weird incompatibility between the pear library and my smtp as it works with eg. google fine.

Comment: that's why I told to check what error message you really get from the server. Without that information, it is impossible to find out what's wrong.